# Cloud Run + Firebase Hosting region rewrites issue

Tags: firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to use Firebase Hosting for CDN connected to Cloud Run. Yesterday I was testing something for region *eu-west1* and it went well. Today I'm trying to do the same but for region *eu-west4* and I'm getting error that this region is not supported.
I switched to *eu-west1* and it worked.

Is this bug or region eu-west4 is not supported?

```
=== Deploying to 'xxxxxxxx'...
i  deploying hosting
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Cloud Run region `europe-west4` is not supported.
```

```js
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "web-client",
          "region": "europe-west4"
        }
      }
    ],
```

same for new asia-southeast1 region also

```
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Cloud Run region `asia-southeast1` is not supported.
```

Comment: You can find [Cloud Run region here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/locations). However, I don't know if firebase can use it. If it's a limitation, I bet for a Firebase one.

Comment: I'm curious. Is this behavior present for any other Region you choose different to _eu-west1_ ?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2051

Comment: @KevinQuinzel I asked with cloud run team privately, from above link I found Firebase Hosting to Cloud Run rewrite availability is there, some regions don't have rewrite support!

Comment: @Mistic92 Did you understand why you can't deploy your hosting? I'm facing the exact same error, but I'm using `europe-west1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [info](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2051) here is the Details information regarding Rewrite:

Firebase Hosting originates in *us-central1* so while deploying cloud Run it's recommended to select us-central1 region for less First Contentful Paint score or quick loading of your website, but kills the advantage of your nearby region availability purpose(really unfortunate for google fanboys).

Example: if your location is India your nearest  cloud run available is *asia-southeast1* Singapore we can't select  *asia-southeast1*

**Request path would go like this:**

**you→India(CDN)→USA(Firebase)→Signapore(CloudRun+aync call to Firestore India)→USA→CDN→you** (which is REALLY BAD in terms of latency).

**you→India(CDN)→USA(Firebase)→USA us-central1(CloudRun+aync call to Firestore India)→USA→CDN→you**

(static Page will Load FAST, but Firestore dynamic data on webapp will data load with REALLY BAD in terms of latency, we should select *us-central1* for Firestore also this makes no use of your local region GCP products this really strange that Firebase hosting not available for at least for AMERICA EUROPE ASIA-PACIFIC zones atleast).

**Conclusion(till this date):**

Cloud Run region rewrites issue for Firebase Hosting is there for many regions but, for the optimal page load result we should select *us-central1* it is really unfortunate THIS IS THE REAL PROBLEM compare to Rewrite Issue, to avoid website Firestore latency for non USA users we should use cloud run/cloud function cache control such that data will cached at your local/near by region CDN for fast data loading (we cant use firebase web SDK since CDN caching not possible via if we use SDK, we should use Cloud function in firebase/cloud run)

Firebase Hosting to Cloud Run rewrite availability ( as of Aug 31, 2020)

**Available:**

us-central1,
us-east1,
asia-northeast1,
europe-west1

**Not available**
asia-east1,
europe-north1,
europe-west4,
us-east4,
us-west1,
asia-southeast1

Please file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) for Firebase rewrite availability if it's not available in your region Cloud Run and Firebase hosting not available for at least for AMERICA EUROPE ASIA-PACIFIC zones.

FYI: Cloud Firestore [multi-region](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations#multi-region) also not available for Asia region if using multi-region Firestore is the fix for locked Firebase hosting and Cloud run regions to *us-central1*

[Cloud Run availability region](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations#asia-pacific)

*(Please comment if you get the rewrite access to any of the above mentioned region)*

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to figure out a way to "fix" this. I changed my regions to `europe-west4` instead of my previous `europe-west1` and that "fixed" my deployment problem.